# java.lang.IllegalStateException after first successful test run

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, illegalstateexception

here is my problem:
I have an android app and want to test the performance of different methods. 
I wrote an android test project and the test is successful when running it the first time. Sometimes also when running it the second, but after a while it fails although I did no code changes. When I deinstall the app, it is successful again for the first run(s). It seems that I have an "activity problem", because the error is an java.lang.IllegalStateException. But for me I can´t even see which activity (does it mean the activity of the app oder of the test project??) and I don´t know how to fix the problem.

My Test file:

```
several imports..

public class PersonalNetworkTest extends
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<PersonalNetworkMainActivity> {

private PersonalNetworkMainActivity mActivity;

public PersonalNetworkTest() {
    super(PersonalNetworkMainActivity.class);
  } 

@Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    mActivity = getActivity();
 }  

public void testPreConditions2() {
    assertTrue(mActivity != null);
    assertTrue(mActivity.getPersonalNetworkInstance() != null);
    PersonalNetwork network = mActivity.getPersonalNetworkInstance();
    String test = "s";      
    network.addAlter(test);
        assertTrue(network.hasAlter(test));
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
```

}

The console give me: Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalStateException'

The LogCat means: (I hope this is the relevant snippet..)

```
06-12 11:07:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(31624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 11:07:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(31624): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not 
                    perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
06-12 11:07:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(31624): at       
                           android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
06-12 11:07:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(31624):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
```

So does any one know what I`m doing wrong? I would be really helpful to get some assistance ..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem happens when to try to `commit` your fragment transaction when the activity is not there. Try using `commitAllowingStateLoss`

Comment: Thrown when an action is attempted at a time when the VM is not in the correct state.so you have finish your current activity .